# Can the responder view his/her answers after submitting Google Forms?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Is there a way that the responder can view his/her answers after he/she clicks submit in Google Forms? I tried looking for answers in Google but still haven't found any.

If there's any way, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Form users can receive an email containing their responses and you can set this up from the form settings (cog icon).

You need to enable 'Collect email addresses' and then also enable 'Response receipts'.

This method assumes the form user is logged into a Google account.

If your users are not using Google for email you would need to include a question that requests their email address in full as a string and then create an apps script function bound to the response sheet and triggered by onFormSubmit() to programmatically send them an email which can include any information you require, including their responses.

Comment: so it is not possible to have a landing page that will contain the user's submission? only thru email?

Comment: This article covers your options here: https://www.abovethecloud.co/blog/4-ways-submitters-can-see-their-google-form-responses